# Add mysqldump to MAMP (MySQL /w Apache PHP on MacOS X)

Tags: mysql, macos

I wonder how I can add mysqldump to my MAMP environment. I googled a bit and found only the community MySQL server version. But I do not want to install another MySQL – basically because I want to save my data first, before any experiment.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Found the solution on my own. Maybe this helps other Mac users...
In fact mysqldump ships with MAMP but is located somewhere in the desert:

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump

That´s why tools like MySQL workbench do not find it, neither does it work in terminal without the path. So finally just type:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -u yourUser -p --opt yourdb > yourdump.sql
```

to create a dump.

Comment: sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump /usr/local/bin/mysqldump

Comment: true. adding the symlink is actually a nice additional hint here. thanks Matthew.

Comment: If the managment window appear empty after this, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25408447/3307382

Comment: Thank you. I had to select /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin for DBeaver Local Client Home because I only have MAMP Pro 6.6 MySQL 5.7 installed on macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 19):

In `.bash_profile`, add `PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin"`.

If you don't have a `.bash_profile`, you can [create one](http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac).

Comment: maybe it should be an `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin"`

Answer (score 11):

I've recently discovered that MAMP PRO hides all your mysql terminal abilities.

Using this though copies all the mamp Mysql magic over to your local bin, where you can start using all wp-cli db functions again or anything that you need with databases via terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql; 
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck /usr/local/bin/mysqlcheck; 
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump /usr/local/bin/mysqldump
```

Answer (score 1):

This will helps you to resolve:

1. In your home directory create or edit the file `.bash_profile` you can access your home directory by typing: `cd ~/`
2. Add this to the top of the file:

   `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin`
3. Save the file and then restart your Terminal
4. In your newly restarted Terminal window type: `mysql –version`

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/mysql-5.6.20-osx10.8-x86_64/bin/mysqldump -u root  -p  databasename tablename > /Library/WebServer/Documents/upload/kg_exam_metadata.sql;

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.