# Mysql Workbench Mac OS missing management tools and Data Import/Export

Tags: mysql, macos, operating-system, workbench

All management tools are missing (left tab on screenshot) and Data Import and Export menu options does nothing.

I have downloaded the official installation **mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-osx-i686** and tried installing multiple times, without success.

Newly created schemas work without issues and I can connect to the dababases.

[image: Mysql Workbench 6.1 on Mac Os]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Im posting it here to help others.

Press (i) on the connection box and then run "Configure local management.." completing all
steps on the window that is opened. After that opening the connection will show the management
tools and data import/export then works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've spent a long time trying to figure this one out!  I'm now a disgruntled Workbench user, but thanks to you I'm now able to use the full functionality.

Comment: Just found this, and in version 6.3.7 (MacOS) the button isn't called "Configure Local Management ..." but rather it's called "Connect"; nevertheless this helped me out of a problem, much appreciated!

Comment: Wow, they sure hide that. Thanks.